# store application database even after the App is deleted to be accessed next time the app is installed

Tags: iphone, database, memory, store, nsdocumentdirectory

I am working on core data and need to know if there exists some approach that i can follow to access  the database file even after the app is deleted.

I cant use any server to upload the this file or photo library.

I need to know is there any other storage on iphone my app can use to store the database so that next time the database is readable.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: No. If you dont want to use your server to store the data, then there is no any way to achieve this thing. Because if your app will contain in-app purchase then apple will automatically downolad your previously deleted data. but in your case it is not possible

Comment: Is it possible to do some modification in iPhone Preferences or bundle etc ?

Comment: you can generate a CSV file with DB content and send it via email. Then, you can implement an import method to restore the data. And for the photos, you can save them in photolibrary.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering your question, yes this is possible using the [KeyChain services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html). Even when the app is deleted, the data will still exist in the keychain and can be accessed again from the same application. The data will stay until the keychain is cleared or the iPhone OS is reset.

However this is NOT what the keychain was meant for. It is not meant to be used as a database. I would find a way around your uploading to server limitation.

Perhaps you could use the keychain to store some sort of sensitive information that would allow them to retrieve the data from a server.